# eas submit ios fails with Asset validation failed The app references non-public selectors in Payload

Tags: ios, expo, app-store, app-store-connect, eas

I have a managed workflow expo app which I am trying to submit to App Store. The build was successful but the submission from project directory (cannot use xCode due to managed workflow) fails with the error " Asset validation failed The app references non-public selectors in Payload/{appName}.app/{appName}: _isKeyDown, _modifiedInput, _modifierFlags

My eas.json looks like this:

```
 {
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.7.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "developmentClient": true,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"

      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "developmentClient": true,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"

      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "developmentClient": true,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"

      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "******",
        "ascAppId": "******",
        "appleTeamId": "******",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my app.json like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "******",
    "slug": "******",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "******",
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "******",
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "******",
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your videos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I have no clue as to what goes wrong here and unfortunately all other solutions referencing this error refer to xCode settings which can be altered, but again not an option here since I am using the managed workflow of expo...
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: please how did you solve this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using eas build,check your eas.json:

```
"production": {
"developmentClient": false,
"distribution": "store",
"channel": "production"
}
```

**developmentClient** should be "**false**"