# Can I upload an Expo Dev Client to testflight?

Tags: expo, eas

I am trying to upload an expo-devclient using the `development-testflight` build profile (and I also tried EAS submit)

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "development-testflight": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {},
    "development-testflight": {},
  }
}
```

But it fails without any error on the Transporter app.

When using EAS submit I get this error [eas submit ios fails with Asset validation failed The app references non-public selectors in Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941095/eas-submit-ios-fails-with-asset-validation-failed-the-app-references-non-public) (the question I linked is because someone was trying to upload a devclient as the produciton build inadvertently, but in my case I am intending to upload the devclient)

I am trying to do this to simplify the distribution of the customized dev client for the developers so we don't have to register devices.